# Не получается отправлять письма с данными из Django

Tags: python, django

На сайте создал форму для отправки имени, фамилии и почты посетителя сайта, на мою почту сообщением. При положительной отправке сообщения с основной страницы посетитель попадает на страницу с надписью "Success!". Но, проблема в том, что хоть и происходит переход на страницу с положительным ответом, письма с данными посетителя мне на почту не приходят и от этого я в замешательстве!

Вот весь код касающийся проблемы:

urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.indexLite, name='index'),
    path('success/', views.successView, name = 'success'),
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

settings.py:

```
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.mail.ru'
EMAIL_PORT = 2525
EMAIL_HOST_USER = "daribian@list.ru"
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = "***********"
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
```

views.py:

```
from django.core.mail import send_mail, BadHeaderError
from django.http import HttpResponse,HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from django.conf import settings

from .forms import UserForm

def indexLite(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        form = UserForm()
    else:
        form = UserForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            firstname= form.cleaned_data['first_name']
            lastname= form.cleaned_data['last_name']
            emailvalue= form.cleaned_data['email']
            try:
                send_mail = (firstname, lastname, settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER, ['daribian@list.ru'])
            except BadHeaderError:
                return HttpResponse('Invalid header found.')
            return redirect('success')
    return render(request, 'index.html', {'form': form})

def successView(request):
    return HttpResponse('Success!')
```

forms.py:

```
from django import forms

class UserForm(forms.Form):
     first_name = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class' : 'my_name_class'}),max_length=100, required=True)
     last_name = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class' : 'my_last_lass'}), max_length=100, required=True)
     email= forms.EmailField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class' : 'my_email_class'}), required=True)
```

Сама форма:

```
<form class="form_contact" action="" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <div>
             <input type="submit" name="submit" value="button" class="form_button">
        </div>
</form>
```

Возможно здесь мне кто-то расскажет что является причиной данной проблемы!

Comment: Вы нигде не вызываете функцию отправки письма, вот оно и не отправляется.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В блоке `try` в файле `views.py` нужно удалить знак `=` и пробелы, чтобы получился вызов функции

```
send_mail(firstname, lastname, settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER, ['daribian@list.ru'])
```

Comment: Спасибо вам! Сейчас так стыдно стало)